# Docker Windows 10 Home: mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 2 column 18 (Psych::SyntaxError)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm having a problem when I try to run `docker-compose up`. The error says `mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 2 column 18 (Psych::SyntaxError)` in my terminal. I've browsed similar questions and believe I've tried all and haven't been able to find suitable answers.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    command: [--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password]
    ports:
      - "3610:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=db_name_here_db
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/mysql:rw
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    ports:
      - "3002:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      DB_NAME: db_name_here
      DB_USER: root
      DB_PASSWORD: password
      DB_HOST: db
```

Comment: Is your web image building and running? looks like a ruby config issue not docker

Comment: I've tried docker ps it gives me a container that status is restarting what seems to be the problem here? I've tried `docker-compose down` and `up` again and it seems to have the same issue

Comment: is `docker logs` showing something?

Comment: yes some errors would show like this `/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/psych.rb:402:in `parse': (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 2 column 18 (Psych::SyntaxError)`

Comment: That's comming from malformed YAML. Check your rubi script syntax, using a lint tool.

Comment: Hi, i've fixed this issue there seems to have //codehere in my database.yml file and so the error was gone.. But now I have another issue which is `/file_name/config/boot.rb:2:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Psych::ENGINE (NameError)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docker-compose.yml is tab / space sensitive. It looks like you have an extra tab on your services or somewhere at the top of your file.

Comment: I also tried the yml validator and it shows no errors in my end

Comment: By YML validator did you run docker-compose config

Comment: yes I did run it. but the problem I'm getting at is always on that error

Comment: Id recommend using shift-tab to left align your entire docker-compose file then going through and adding proper tabs again. If that is not the issue temporarily remove your entire rails configuration from the docker-compose.yml and see if it runs successfully against the database. If that works insert the rails code and comment the command. If that runs (and exits) then replace the command. That will eliminate it to being either your Dockerfile or Rails app. Also, you can try pruning your system docker system prune -a and docker volume prune (Warning: data can be lost)